Could not find com.google.android:cameraview:1.0.0
I am trying to build my app in react native using the command - eas build -p android --profile preview.
With the above command, I got the url in the terminal which has the link to the build of the app in eas website.
There is one task which is failing - Run gradlew, below are the output of that task.
Running 'gradlew :app:assembleRelease' in /home/expo/workingdir/build/android
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.6-all.zip
10%.
20%.
30%.
40%.
50%.
60%.
70%.
80%.
90%.
100%
Welcome to Gradle 8.6!
Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Configurable encryption key for configuration cache
 - Build init improvements
 - Build authoring improvements
For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/8.6/release-notes.html
To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.6/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon in the Gradle documentation.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build
Path for java installation '/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-17' (Common Linux Locations) does not contain a java executable
> Task :gradle-plugin:checkKotlinGradlePluginConfigurationErrors
> Task :expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin:checkKotlinGradlePluginConfigurationErrors
> Task :expo-updates-gradle-plugin:checkKotlinGradlePluginConfigurationErrors
> Task :expo-updates-gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors
> Task :expo-updates-gradle-plugin:processResources
> Task :expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors
> Task :expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin:processResources
> Task :gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors
> Task :gradle-plugin:processResources
> Task :expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin
> Task :expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin:classes
> Task :expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin:jar
> Task :gradle-plugin:compileKotlin
> Task :gradle-plugin:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :gradle-plugin:classes
> Task :gradle-plugin:jar
> Task :expo-updates-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin
> Task :expo-updates-gradle-plugin:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :expo-updates-gradle-plugin:classes
> Task :expo-updates-gradle-plugin:jar
> Configure project :app
ℹ️  [33mApplying gradle plugin[0m '[32mexpo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin[0m' (expo-dev-launcher@4.0.15)
 ℹ️  [33mApplying gradle plugin[0m '[32mexpo-updates-gradle-plugin[0m' (expo-updates@0.25.14)
> Configure project :expo-modules-core
Checking the license for package NDK (Side by side) 26.1.10909125 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/licenses
License for package NDK (Side by side) 26.1.10909125 accepted.
Preparing "Install NDK (Side by side) 26.1.10909125 v.26.1.10909125".
"Install NDK (Side by side) 26.1.10909125 v.26.1.10909125" ready.
Installing NDK (Side by side) 26.1.10909125 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125
"Install NDK (Side by side) 26.1.10909125 v.26.1.10909125" complete.
"Install NDK (Side by side) 26.1.10909125 v.26.1.10909125" finished.
> Configure project :expo
Using expo modules
  - [32mexpo-asset[0m (10.0.6)
  - [32mexpo-camera[0m (15.0.9)
  - [32mexpo-constants[0m (16.0.1)
  - [32mexpo-dev-client[0m (4.0.14)
  - [32mexpo-dev-launcher[0m (4.0.15)
  - [32mexpo-dev-menu[0m (5.0.14)
  - [32mexpo-device[0m (6.0.2)
  - [32mexpo-eas-client[0m (0.12.0)
  - [32mexpo-file-system[0m (17.0.1)
  - [32mexpo-font[0m (12.0.5)
  - [32mexpo-json-utils[0m (0.13.1)
  - [32mexpo-keep-awake[0m (13.0.2)
  - [32mexpo-manifests[0m (0.14.3)
  - [32mexpo-modules-core[0m (1.12.11)
  - [32mexpo-secure-store[0m (13.0.1)
  - [32mexpo-splash-screen[0m (0.27.4)
  - [32mexpo-structured-headers[0m (3.8.0)
  - [32mexpo-system-ui[0m (3.0.4)
  - [32mexpo-updates[0m (0.25.14)
- [32mexpo-web-browser[0m (13.0.3)
> Configure project :react-native-reanimated
Android gradle plugin: 8.2.1
Gradle: 8.6
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 34 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/licenses
License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 34 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 34 v.34.0.0".
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 34 v.34.0.0" ready.
Installing Android SDK Build-Tools 34 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/build-tools/34.0.0
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 34 v.34.0.0" complete.
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 34 v.34.0.0" finished.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 34 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/licenses
License for package Android SDK Platform 34 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 34 (revision 3)".
"Install Android SDK Platform 34 (revision 3)" ready.
Installing Android SDK Platform 34 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-34
"Install Android SDK Platform 34 (revision 3)" complete.
"Install Android SDK Platform 34 (revision 3)" finished.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalReportRelease'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:releaseCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not find com.google.android:cameraview:1.0.0.
     Required by:
         project :app > project :expo > project :expo-camera
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
BUILD FAILED in 3m 31s
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.6/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
15 actionable tasks: 15 executed
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.

Updated -
The contents of android/build.gradle is -
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = findProperty('android.buildToolsVersion') ?: '34.0.0'
        minSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.minSdkVersion') ?: '23')
        compileSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.compileSdkVersion') ?: '34')
        targetSdkVersion = Integer.parseInt(findProperty('android.targetSdkVersion') ?: '34')
        kotlinVersion = findProperty('android.kotlinVersion') ?: '1.9.23'

        ndkVersion = "26.1.10909125"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle')
        classpath('com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin')
        classpath('org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin')
    }
}

apply plugin: "com.facebook.react.rootproject"

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url(new File(['node', '--print', "require.resolve('react-native/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), '../android'))
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url(new File(['node', '--print', "require.resolve('jsc-android/package.json', { paths: [require.resolve('react-native/package.json')] })"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), '../dist'))
        }

        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            // expo-camera bundles a custom com.google.android:cameraview
            url "$rootDir/../node_modules/expo-camera/android/maven"
        }
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
    }
}
// @generated begin expo-camera-import - expo prebuild (DO NOT MODIFY) sync-f244f4f3d8bf7229102e8f992b525b8602c74770
def expoCameraMavenPath = new File(["node", "--print", "require.resolve('expo-camera/package.json')"].execute(null, rootDir).text.trim(), "../android/maven")
allprojects { 
    repositories { 
        maven { url(expoCameraMavenPath) }
        maven {
                // expo-camera bundles a custom com.google.android:cameraview
                url "$rootDir/../node_modules/expo-camera/android/maven"
            }
} }
// @generated end expo-camera-import

Here is the new error -
Running 'gradlew :app:assembleRelease' in /home/expo/workingdir/build/android
Downloading https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.6-all.zip
10%.
20%.
30%.
40%.
50%.
60%.
70%.
80%.
90%.
100%
Welcome to Gradle 8.6!
Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Configurable encryption key for configuration cache
- Build init improvements
 - Build authoring improvements
For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/8.6/release-notes.html
To honour the JVM settings for this build a single-use Daemon process will be forked. For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.6/userguide/gradle_daemon.html#sec:disabling_the_daemon in the Gradle documentation.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build
Path for java installation '/usr/lib/jvm/openjdk-17' (Common Linux Locations) does not contain a java executable
> Task :gradle-plugin:checkKotlinGradlePluginConfigurationErrors
> Task :expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin:checkKotlinGradlePluginConfigurationErrors
> Task :expo-updates-gradle-plugin:checkKotlinGradlePluginConfigurationErrors
> Task :expo-updates-gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors
> Task :expo-updates-gradle-plugin:processResources
> Task :expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors
> Task :expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin:processResources
> Task :gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors
> Task :gradle-plugin:processResources
> Task :expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin
> Task :expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin:classes
> Task :expo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin:jar
> Task :gradle-plugin:compileKotlin
> Task :gradle-plugin:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :gradle-plugin:classes
> Task :gradle-plugin:jar
> Task :expo-updates-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin
> Task :expo-updates-gradle-plugin:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :expo-updates-gradle-plugin:classes
> Task :expo-updates-gradle-plugin:jar
> Configure project :app
 ℹ️  [33mApplying gradle plugin[0m '[32mexpo-dev-launcher-gradle-plugin[0m' (expo-dev-launcher@4.0.15)
 ℹ️  [33mApplying gradle plugin[0m '[32mexpo-updates-gradle-plugin[0m' (expo-updates@0.25.14)
> Configure project :expo-modules-core
Checking the license for package NDK (Side by side) 26.1.10909125 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/licenses
License for package NDK (Side by side) 26.1.10909125 accepted.
Preparing "Install NDK (Side by side) 26.1.10909125 v.26.1.10909125".
"Install NDK (Side by side) 26.1.10909125 v.26.1.10909125" ready.
Installing NDK (Side by side) 26.1.10909125 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/ndk/26.1.10909125
"Install NDK (Side by side) 26.1.10909125 v.26.1.10909125" complete.
"Install NDK (Side by side) 26.1.10909125 v.26.1.10909125" finished.
> Configure project :expo
Using expo modules
  - [32mexpo-asset[0m (10.0.6)
  - [32mexpo-camera[0m (15.0.9)
  - [32mexpo-constants[0m (16.0.1)
  - [32mexpo-dev-client[0m (4.0.14)
  - [32mexpo-dev-launcher[0m (4.0.15)
  - [32mexpo-dev-menu[0m (5.0.14)
  - [32mexpo-device[0m (6.0.2)
  - [32mexpo-eas-client[0m (0.12.0)
  - [32mexpo-file-system[0m (17.0.1)
  - [32mexpo-font[0m (12.0.5)
  - [32mexpo-json-utils[0m (0.13.1)
  - [32mexpo-keep-awake[0m (13.0.2)
- [32mexpo-manifests[0m (0.14.3)
  - [32mexpo-modules-core[0m (1.12.11)
  - [32mexpo-secure-store[0m (13.0.1)
- [32mexpo-splash-screen[0m (0.27.4)
  - [32mexpo-structured-headers[0m (3.8.0)
  - [32mexpo-system-ui[0m (3.0.4)
  - [32mexpo-updates[0m (0.25.14)
- [32mexpo-web-browser[0m (13.0.3)
> Configure project :react-native-reanimated
Android gradle plugin: 8.2.1
Gradle: 8.6
Checking the license for package Android SDK Build-Tools 34 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/licenses
License for package Android SDK Build-Tools 34 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Build-Tools 34 v.34.0.0".
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 34 v.34.0.0" ready.
Installing Android SDK Build-Tools 34 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/build-tools/34.0.0
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 34 v.34.0.0" complete.
"Install Android SDK Build-Tools 34 v.34.0.0" finished.
Checking the license for package Android SDK Platform 34 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/licenses
License for package Android SDK Platform 34 accepted.
Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 34 (revision 3)".
"Install Android SDK Platform 34 (revision 3)" ready.
Installing Android SDK Platform 34 in /home/expo/Android/Sdk/platforms/android-34
"Install Android SDK Platform 34 (revision 3)" complete.
"Install Android SDK Platform 34 (revision 3)" finished.
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:lintVitalReportRelease'.
> Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:releaseCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve project :react-native-camera.
     Required by:
         project :app
      > The consumer was configured to find a library for use during compile-time, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.2.1', attribute 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type' with value 'androidJvm'. However we cannot choose between the following variants of project :react-native-camera:
          - generalReleaseApiElements
          - mlkitReleaseApiElements
        All of them match the consumer attributes:
          - Variant 'generalReleaseApiElements' capability SauravApp:react-native-camera:unspecified declares a component for use during compile-time, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.2.1', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release'
:
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.ProductFlavor:react-native-camera' with value 'general' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr' with value 'generalRelease' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Doesn't say anything about its component category (required a library)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type (required 'androidJvm')
                  - Provides attribute 'react-native-camera' with value 'general' but the consumer didn't ask for it
- Variant 'mlkitReleaseApiElements' capability SauravApp:react-native-camera:unspecified declares a component for use during compile-time, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.2.1', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release':
              - Unmatched attributes:
                  - Provides attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.ProductFlavor:react-native-camera' with value 'mlkit' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Provides attribute 'com.android.build.gradle.internal.attributes.VariantAttr' with value 'mlkitRelease' but the consumer didn't ask for it
                  - Doesn't say anything about its component category (required a library)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type (required 'androidJvm')
                  - Provides attribute 'react-native-camera' with value 'mlkit' but the consumer didn't ask for it
        The following variants were also considered but didn't match the requested attributes:
          - Variant 'generalDebugApiElements' capability SauravApp:react-native-camera:unspecified declares a component for use during compile-time, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.2.1':
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its component category (required a library)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type (required 'androidJvm')
          - Variant 'generalDebugRuntimeElements' capability SauravApp:react-native-camera:unspecified declares a component for use during runtime, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.2.1':
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its component category (required a library)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type (required 'androidJvm')
          - Variant 'mlkitDebugApiElements' capability SauravApp:react-native-camera:unspecified declares a component for use during compile-time, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.2.1':
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its component category (required a library)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type (required 'androidJvm')
          - Variant 'mlkitDebugRuntimeElements' capability SauravApp:react-native-camera:unspecified declares a component for use during runtime, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '8.2.1':
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug' and the consumer needed a component, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'release'
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its component category (required a library)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for Android)
                  - Doesn't say anything about org.jetbrains.kotlin.platform.type (required 'androidJvm')
* Try:
> Ambiguity errors are explained in more detail at https://docs.gradle.org/8.6/userguide/variant_model.html#sub:variant-ambiguity.
> Review the variant matching algorithm at https://docs.gradle.org/8.6/userguide/variant_attributes.html#sec:abm_algorithm.
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
> Get more help at https://help.gradle.org.
BUILD FAILED in 3m 16s
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
For more on this, please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/8.6/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings in the Gradle documentation.
15 actionable tasks: 15 executed
Error: Gradle build failed with unknown error. See logs for the "Run gradlew" phase for more information.

Here is the content of my package.json -
{
  "name": "myfolder",
  "main": "./App.tsx",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "reset-project": "node ./scripts/reset-project.js",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios",
    "web": "expo start --web",
    "test": "jest --watchAll",
    "lint": "expo lint"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-expo"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@expo/html-elements": "^0.10.1",
    "@expo/metro-runtime": "^3.2.1",
    "@expo/vector-icons": "^14.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.17",
    "expo": "~51.0.8",
    "expo-build-properties": "~0.12.1",
    "expo-camera": "~15.0.9",
    "expo-constants": "~16.0.1",
    "expo-dev-client": "~4.0.14",
    "expo-device": "~6.0.2",
    "expo-font": "~12.0.5",
    "expo-linking": "~6.3.1",
    "expo-router": "~3.5.14",
    "expo-secure-store": "~13.0.1",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.27.4",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.12.1",
    "expo-system-ui": "~3.0.4",
    "expo-updates": "~0.25.14",
    "expo-web-browser": "~13.0.3",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "pod-install": "0.1.38",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.74.1",
    "react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.16.1",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.11.0",
    "react-native-otp-verify": "^1.1.8",
    "react-native-permissions": "^4.1.5",
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.5.5",
    "react-native-reanimated": "~3.10.1",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.10.1",
    "react-native-screen": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-screens": "3.31.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.19.10",
    "react-native-webview": "13.8.6",
    "react-navigation": "^5.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.29",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.12",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.6",
    "@types/react": "~18.2.45",
    "@types/react-navigation": "^3.4.0",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.7",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.8",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "jest-expo": "~51.0.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.3.3"
  },
  "private": true
}


https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/15937

@Phil I have tried the solution provided in the link you shared. But it didn't resolve the issue. I have pasted the updated build.gradle file in the above post.

Encountered the same issue. Seems like it is related to expo's service downtime.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
